Requested entity was not found
Client error: POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectID>/messages:send resulted in a 404 Not Found response:
{
"error": {
"code": 404,

"message": "Requested entity was not found.",

"status": "NOT_FOUND",

"detail (truncated...)

}
}
` $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects//messages:send';
$credentialsFilePath = public_path('assets/json/serviceAccountKey.json');
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($credentialsFilePath);
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
$access_token = $token['access_token'];
    $data = [
        'message' => [
            'token' => 'c25j-m60SbKdHZD_uYXihm:APA91bEsuOXz4-xTK0eMJeX_5Wcu7gaD4ci8zZqWSSpKMmhfrrlzndSrGOU7WCmbH56aSMQCL3pTAEkD47UvvTBXOg12FPRMIPSPp2YOiV1ZJA4Gvp_o-yXLl24QNhUlQsuFVOg5cHCQ',
            'notification' => [
                'title' => $options['title'],
                'body' => $options['body'],
            ],
            'data' => [
                'category' => $options['category'],
                'isAction' => $options['isAction'],
                'isSOSActive' => $options['isSOSActive'],

            ],
        ],
    ];
    $encodedData = json_encode($data);
    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$access_token,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
         'body' => $encodedData,
         'verify' => true,  // need enable SSL verification in production
    ]);`


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Client error: POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectID>/messages:send resulted in a 404 Not Found response:
{
"error": {
"code": 404,

"message": "Requested entity was not found.",

"status": "NOT_FOUND",

"detail (truncated...)

I got this error when i try to send push notification

I just got the same error. It was working before without any problem. Did you find a solution? Maybe it's from Google's end.

The problem with my case was that I was using an expired Firebase Token for the device I was trying to send the notificaiton.
